# Merge two xcode projects and run based on condition

Tags: ios, xcode, merge

I want to merge two Xcode projects.

I have two Xcode projects Project A and Project B. Both run fine separately and both have different concepts. Now I want to combine this two projects and run based on their respective condition.

What I want is when I am connected to WIFI A I want to run project A(Target of A) and when I am connected two WIFI B I want to run project B(Target of B).

I have tried workspace in that I have added both projects , but now i don't know what I have to do.

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Long-story-short; you're going to have to create a single project containing the classes of both source projects.  At runtime you'll need to make the decision about which pseudo-project classes to use, and that's pretty much it.  You won't get a sensible answer as the question is not specific enough.

Comment: @trojanfoe: i think i have added things which i want ? anything else you want to know for better help ?

Answer (score 0):

you can't have xcode set up to build&run a specific target based on the wifi.

---

you could set up a construct using OSX Locations feature and some app that executes certain actions based on your location but that wouldn't be with xcode at all

e.g.

1.
- if location == office then make a symbolic link from WORKING_PROCT to folder A
- if location == home then make a symbolic link from WORKING_PROCT to folder B

1. close xcode if A or B is open
2. open WORKING_PROJECT with xcode

==> but that would best be discussed on superuser

Comment: what VDPATEL want to ask see this link if you give answer please http://stackoverflow.com/q/24820384/1559675