# How to open .xcodeproj programmatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, merge, project

I have projects called A.xcodeproj, B.xcodeproj, C.xcodeproj

now what is question, in AppDelegate of Project A , open project B and C on condition.

```
int run;

run = 0;

if(run == 0)
{
    Open project B.xcodeproj
}
else
{
    Open project C.xcodeproj
}
```

Help

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

on the command line use `open` to OPEN and SHOW xcode..
 so in your case, when `run == 0`

when you want to BUILD the xcode project, invoke `xcodebuild` instead of open!..
so in your case, when `run == 1`

Comment: sorry mate I am not able to understand will you provide any code please Note: I am not asking for when my "run" will make 1. I want code that open project programmatically.